# Enumerating rooted forests/trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

A rooted forest on $\{1,...,n\}$ is a forest together with a choice of a root in each component tree.
Let $F(n,k)$ be the set of all rooted forests that consist
of $k$ rooted trees.
Thus $F(n,1)$ is the set of all rooted trees.

**Question**:
Enumerate all elements of the set $F(3,1)$.
I think it should be only 3 as follows:

[image]

But the answer says 9.
Can someone enumerate those for me?

Comment: Are the trees labeled? unlabeled?

Comment: What about the trees with 1 terminal node?

Comment: @TheHolyJoker the trees are labeled. that's why all 3 graphs above are considered distinct otherwise they would be considered same.

Comment: @kimchilover all nodes must be part of only one tree so there must be two leaf nodes and one root because there are total of three nodes

Comment: My grandmother, mother, and I are 3 nodes of a tree rooted at my gm and with 1 terminal node, namely me.

Comment: @kimchilover oh right. but then why is cayley number $T_3=3?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *rooted* tree is a labeled tree where one of the vertices is chosen to be the root. You have listed all labeled trees, but have not chosen the root for each. There are three choices for the root for each of the three labeled trees, so there are $9$ rooted trees in $F(3,1)$. They look like this:

[image]